# SQL Server 2005 statements returning the same results

Tags: sql-server-2005, gridview

Why are these two statements returning the same results? I'm looking at the total number of orders and the sum of the prices for some publications. The first statement gets records from the past 24 hours and the second one is supposed to show the same sums but from the start of the month to the current date. When I look at the gridviews to which they are filling, it looks like BOTH of them are displaying the sums from the past 24 hours. Anything noticeable?

```
SELECT pubName AS Publication, COUNT(*) AS Total, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(CAST(price AS DECIMAL))) AS Price FROM [SecureOrders] WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) GROUP BY pubName

SELECT pubName AS Publication, COUNT(*) AS Total, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(CAST(price AS DECIMAL))) AS Price FROM [SecureOrders] WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) GROUP BY pubName
```

Comment: Try running the query in SSMS. If you have orders between the 1st of the month and this time yesterday they should return different results. Wonder if you are hitting some caching issue in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF one of them is supposed to be the past 24 hours, you should be looking at hours.

```
SELECT
    pubName AS Publication
    ,COUNT(*) AS Total
    ,'$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(CAST(price AS DECIMAL))) AS Price
FROM [SecureOrders] 
WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
GROUP BY pubName
```

Otherwise the dates are perfectly fine in both...assuming the DateTime column is in fact DateTime I would check the datasources for the grid.

Comment: I've got the correct datasources attached to each grid. It's really odd why I'm not able to extract the correct information for the "month to date" Grid. But thanks for the hours - that's just what I was looking for on that side!

Comment: I've got it! It was simply the wrong database being used - boy do I feel stupid now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the DateDiff clause. Maybe I'm missing something.

<strike>SELECT pubName AS Publication, COUNT(*) AS Total, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(CAST(price AS DECIMAL))) AS Price FROM [SecureOrders] WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) GROUP BY pubName</strike>

Edit: Ignore the above, I was being dense(r).

Comment: I presume you didn't run this and compare to the OP's original one.

Comment: Doh! we'll put that one down to the dangers of early evening sql, shall we.